# Kendogrid not clickable in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, kendo-ui

I have a problem with the KendoGrid not being clickable in Chrome anymore. When I test it in IE it works fine. When a colleague of mine tests it on his pc with Chrome it also works so it must be something to do with my settings.

I have the latest version of Chrome installed. It once worked but apparently I did something wrong but I can't solve it.

Any help would do !

Thanks !

Comment: What version do you use (did you try the latest version)? What operating system do you use, is it Win8 with touch screen?

Comment: It happened to one of the computers in our organization as well: Win7/Chrome doesn't fire up the click event, as if it doesn't registers at all (maybe it registers before the grid is rendered).

the following [thread](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/grid-selectable-and-groupable-not-working-in-chrome.aspx) didn't yield much information either.

Comment: Chrome changed the way that they handle click events at one point and we had to react fast. Not sure if your issue is related, but can you test with the lastest bits?  Thats 2013.1.319.